# correlation and constant variable problem

Tags: correlation

I want to know if word length has an effect of being remembered or not by students. I conducted a test and entered each word as dichotomous variable (0-1, not remembered-remembered). However word lengths are constant and cannot be correlated. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do anything about it except start over and do the test with words of different lengths.